# Get very next word of a substring in a string

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to get the next word of a word in a string. I tried to write a script but it's not working. And it's good if you suggest me any other alternatives to achieve this.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
opts="OPTS=\"-name user -age 20 -where Asia -eats Brains\""
echo $opts
ok="0"
for word in $opts; do
  if [ "$word" = "-where" ] ; then
    if [ "$ok" = "1" ] ; then
      echo $word
      break
    fi
    ok="1"
  fi
done
```

I want to get the word after "-where". But above script not working. I didn't understand where I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to hire `grep` for this job:

```
$ OPTS="\"-name user -age 20 -where Asia -eats Brains\""
$ grep -Po -- '-where \K\w*' <<< "$OPTS"
Asia
```

Explanation:

- `-P`: perl compatible regular expression
- `-o`: show only matching parts
- `\K`: drop everything before that point
- `\w*`: match word constituent (synonym for `[_[:alnum:]]`)

To add `"` to the list of matching characters:

```
$ grep -Po -- '-eats \K[_\"[:alnum:]]*' <<< $OPTS
Brains"
```

Comment: Here is my string: `"\"-name user -age 20 -where Asia -eats Brains\""`. And if I give "-eats" then it should return `Brains"` not `Brain`

Comment: @linux_inside, then change `\w*` to `\S+`.

Comment: @linux_inside You just need to add `"` to the list of matching characters (`\w` match only `alnum` + `_`). See the edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yeah, `\S+` is even simpler.

Comment: Note that with GNU `grep` and `-P`, `\w` and `[[:alnum:]]` only includes non-ASCII alnums in single-byte locales. You may want to add `(*UCP)` to the start of your regexp so it also works in UTF-8 locales (try with `-where=España` for instance).

Answer (score 7):

POSIXly:

```
after_first_where=${opts#*-where }
word_after_where=${after_first_where%% *}
```

Or to allow any number of blanks between words:

```
after_first_where=${opts#*-where}
word_after_where=${after_first_where#"${after_first_where%%[![:blank:]]*}"}
word_after_where=${word_after_where%%[[:blank:]]*}
```

Or you could do:

```
unset -v IFS; set -f # split on blanks, no glob
set -- $opts # splits $opts into $1, $2, $3...
while [ "$#" -ge 2 ]; do
  case $1 in
    (-age|-name|-where|-eats)
       eval "${1#-}=\$2" # assigns name=$2 or where=$2...
       shift 2;;
    (*) shift
  esac
done
printf '%s\n' "$name eats $eats in $where"
```

Note that in that one, blanks are limited to space, tab (and newline) not the other characters that may be considered as `[:blank:]` in your locale.

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

A little edit in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
opts="OPTS=\"-name user -age 20 -where Asia -eats Brains\""
echo $opts
ok="0"
for word in $opts; do
  if [ "$ok" = "1" ] ; then
    echo $word
    break
  fi
  if [ "$word" = "-where" ] ; then
    ok="1"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another POSIX one:

```
printf %s\\n "$opts" | tr -cs '[[:alnum:]-]' '[\n*]' | sed -n '/-where/{
  n
  p
}'
Asia
```

(Note that GNU `tr` won't work with multi bytes characters)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
opts="OPTS=\"-name user -age 20 -where Asia -eats Brains\""
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i~"-where") {print $(i+1)}}}' <<< "$opts"
```

*Output*

```
Asia
```

---

using `tr` and `sed`

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$opts" | sed -n '/-where/{n;p}'
Asia
```

using `tr` and `awk`

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$opts" | awk '/-where/{getline;print;}'
Asia

tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$opts" | awk '/-where/{x=NR+1;next}(NR<=x){print}'
Asia
```